# Command not found: systemctl on Amazon Linux 2018.03

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-linux

I am following [this Amazon AWS guide to install SSL certificates](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-an-instance.html).  I am running Apache on AWS EC2 using the Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.  The first step in the guide is to run:

```
sudo systemctl is-enabled httpd
```

I get "bash: systemctl: command not found".  I suspect maybe I am running Amazon Linux, not Amazon Linux 2.

Comment: First you need to check if systemd package is installed - sudo dpkg -l | grep systemd

Answer (score 41, accepted):

1. First check what Amazon linux version you have runnng on using the
   command `cat /etc/os-release`

   2. If it is Amazon Linux Version 2, then
      it does support systemd and comes installed by default.
   3. If it is
      Amazon linux version 1, then it doesn't support cause Amazon Linux
      is ultimately based on an old version of CentOS/RHEL.

if it is version 1 (amazon linux), you just need to switch to any other linux distribution that supports `systemd`. You can't yum install `systemd` like a package

[image]

Comment: I must be using v1?

Comment: NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2018.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2018.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:amazon:linux:2018.03:ga"
HOME_URL="http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/"

Comment: If v1 should I install systemd?

Comment: As far as I know I would recommend switching to any other distribution of Linux taht supports systemd if operating systemd is mandatory for your requirement.
Cause I don't think it is something that you can install as a package on your OS

Comment: @Jason I confirm that the *Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03* is an "Amazon Linux version 1" that does not come with `systemd` [Announcement: Amazon Linux 2018.03 now available](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=5653). So this is the reason of your issue.

Comment: yes, unfortunately we've to upgrade using amzaon 2 instead. the amazon 1 was obsolete, there'll be a lot of package error / required to use systemd

Comment: How do you disable a service with service.
We also using a Amazon Linux v1 which does not seem to work with systemctl. All I want to achieve is to permanently stop a service without needing to uninstall.

Answer (score 21):

```
sudo service nginx status
```

just use the service command

In earlier versions of RHEL use the `service` command as explained in the [documentation here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s3-services-running-running).

```
# service service_name start
```

Therefore, in your case:

```
# service iptables start
```

You can replace `start` with `restart`, `stop`, `status`.

List all services with:

```
# service --status-all
```