# Getting error in installing minikube kubernates in Amazon Linux EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to install kubernates using mikikube in Amazon-linux EC2 instance. I am following link as https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-workshop-for-kubernetes/blob/master/03-path-application-development/301-local-development/readme.adoc#setup-on-ec2-if-you-do-not-virtualbox-on-your-laptop for the same.
Getting below error while executing

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-15-56 ~]$ minikube start --vm-driver=none
* minikube v1.4.0 on Amazon 2018.03
X The "none" driver requires root privileges. Please run minikube using 'sudo minikube --vm-driver=none'.
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-15-56 ~]$ sudo minikube start --vm-driver=none
sudo: minikube: command not found
```

Also have tried to follow all step under root user but error is same `minikube: command not found`.

Can anyone please help on this.

Answer (score 2):

In user privileges:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-15-56 ~]$which minikube
/path/to/minikube
```

then:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-15-56 ~]$sudo /path/to/minikube --vm-driver=none
```

Answer (score 1):

First way is to use full path to minikube from regular user:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-43-207 ~]$ whereis minikube 
minikube: /usr/local/bin/minikube

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-43-207 ~]$ sudo /usr/local/bin/minikube start --vm-driver=none
  minikube v1.4.0 on Amazon 2018.03 (xen/amd64)
  Running on localhost (CPUs=2, Memory=3945MB, Disk=7997MB) ...
```

Second way is to put your binary to root's default bin location:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-43-207 ~]$ sudo cp /usr/local/bin/minikube /usr/bin/
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-43-207 ~]$ sudo minikube version
minikube version: v1.4.0
commit: 7969c25a98a018b94ea87d949350f3271e9d64b6
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-43-207 ~]$ sudo minikube start --vm-driver=none
  minikube v1.4.0 on Amazon 2018.03 (xen/amd64)
  Running on localhost (CPUs=2, Memory=3945MB, Disk=7997MB) ...
```

Regarding you docker issue in comments: ideally next time this should be separate question.

Yes, reproduced and received the same error as you.

This is the problem of `"Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"` : Its clearly stated by @Vin Odh in [Command not found: systemctl on Amazon Linux 2018.03](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52007149/command-not-found-systemctl-on-amazon-linux-2018-03/52009439#52009439) answer.

`Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03` is an "Amazon Linux version 1" that does not come with `systemd`, so solution is simply use another distributive that works properly, for example I had no problems with

```
Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS (HVM)


ubuntu@ip-172-31-40-246:~$ sudo minikube start --vm-driver=none
  minikube v1.4.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 (xen/amd64)
  Running on localhost (CPUs=2, Memory=3950MB, Disk=7876MB) ...
ℹ️   OS release is Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.16.0 on Docker 18.09.7 ...
  Downloading kubeadm v1.16.0
  Downloading kubelet v1.16.0
  Pulling images ...
  Launching Kubernetes ... 
  Configuring local host environment ...

⚠️  The 'none' driver provides limited isolation and may reduce system security and reliability.
⚠️  For more information, see:
  https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/drivers/none/

⚠️  kubectl and minikube configuration will be stored in /home/ubuntu
⚠️  To use kubectl or minikube commands as your own user, you may need to relocate them. For example, to overwrite your own settings, run:

    ▪ sudo mv /home/ubuntu/.kube /home/ubuntu/.minikube $HOME
    ▪ sudo chown -R $USER $HOME/.kube $HOME/.minikube

  This can also be done automatically by setting the env var CHANGE_MINIKUBE_NONE_USER=true
⌛  Waiting for: apiserver proxy etcd scheduler controller dns
  Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube"
```

Comment: After running with above commands , I can get error as 
`
* minikube v1.4.0 on Amazon 2018.03
* Tip: Use 'minikube start -p <name>' to create a new cluster, or 'minikube delete' to delete this one.
* Starting existing none VM for "minikube" ...
* Waiting for the host to be provisioned ...
*
X Failed to enable container runtime
* Error: [SYSTEMCTL_EXIT_1] running command: sudo systemctl start docker: exit status 1
* Suggestion: Either systemctl is not installed, or Docker is broken. Run 'sudo systemctl start docker' and 'journalctl -u docker'
`